# Create CSV over the hash array loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

In my Rails6 app I want to create admin logger activity with logs exported to CSV files - to do so I'm using paper_trail gem to log all admin activity. I want to store all differences which has been made that's why I'm using `changeset` method from paper_trail gem which gives me below results:

```
[33] pry(main)> PaperTrail::Version.last.changeset
=> {"name"=>["", "no name"], "is_initial_survey_filled"=>[false, true], "updated_at"=>[Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:31:45 UTC +00:00, Mon, 31 Aug 2020 23:43:17 UTC +00:00]}
```

The first value of each key represents old data and the second value from arrays represents new data, like below:

```
name[0] = "" #old data
name[1] = "no name" #new data

is_initial_survey_filled[0] = false #old data
is_initial_survey_filled[1] = true #new data
```

How to fetch and data and put all of these actions inside a CSV file?

I was trying something like this:

```
LOG_HEADERS = ['Created at', 'Acting User', 'Old Data', 'New Data'].freeze

def call
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(base_path)

  CSV.open(file_path, 'w', col_sep: ';', write_headers: true, headers: LOG_HEADERS, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv|
    PaperTrail::Version.all.each do |version|
      old_data_value = version.changeset.present? ? version.changeset.each { |_k, v| v[0] } : ''
      new_data_value = version.changeset.present? ? version.changeset.each { |_k, v| v[1] } : ''
      csv << [version.created_at,
              version.whodunnit,
              old_data_value,
              new_data_value]
    end
  end
end
```

But instead of nice looking logs I'm getting the same data in both columns:

In column old_data:

```
{"name"=>["", "no name"], "is_initial_survey_filled"=>[false, true], "updated_at"=>[Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:31:45 UTC +00:00, Mon, 31 Aug 2020 23:43:17 UTC +00:00]}
```

In column new_data

```
{"name"=>["", "no name"], "is_initial_survey_filled"=>[false, true], "updated_at"=>[Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:31:45 UTC +00:00, Mon, 31 Aug 2020 23:43:17 UTC +00:00]}
```

[EDIT]

Desired CSV should be like:

[image: in attached picture]

Comment: Could you add an example of the desired CSV output to the question? It's not 100% clear how would you like to pack collection(s) (both old and new value are in fact collections, right) into a single CSV column.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `map` method instead of `each`. `each` always returns collection on which it was called. `map` will return data from block passed to it. Changing `version.changeset.each { |_k, v| v[0] } : ''` to `version.changeset.map { |_k, v| v[0] } : ''` will do the job.

Edit: just realized that you want hashes instead of arrays. `version.changeset.map { |k, v| [k, v[0]] }.to_h : ''` will do the job.

Comment: It will do the job with `map` but not with the `.to_h` which gives me an error: `TypeError: wrong element type String at 0 (expected array)`. Besides instead of desired output (at the bottom of my question) I'm getting something like `["name: ", "is_initial_survey_filled: false"]` in one Old Data column instead of two columns like I described.

Comment: You need to change code inside block too(I guess that you missed that part). And you need to do apply same changes in new_data_value too.